# Rectifying aerial photo with known control points in 3d using QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d, georeferencing

Is it possible to rectify an aerial photo with known control points in 3d, in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

While QGIS does not support orthorectification, you can do that in GRASS GIS: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_processing#Orthophotos

Comment: Which GRASS 7 tool uses known 3D (XYZ) control points for orthorectification of an (arial) photo? Is this done via the new GRASS GCP manager (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/wxGUI.gcp.html)?